# 6-oxoheptanal reaction with LiAlH4

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

Is it possible?
the reaction below
[image]

Comment: That isn't 6-oxoheptanal.

Comment: You have lost a carbon, did you intend this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not 6-oxoheptanol and the product cannot be as shown in the snapshot.  You have to keep all the carbon-carbon bonds, and the reactant has secen carbons in the chain versus your product having six.

Lithium aluminum hydride can reduce not only ketones but also carboxylic acids (see [here](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/Carey5th/Ch15/ch15-2-8.html)).  So you are going to convert both of the functional groups to alcohols.  With that in mind, please review how the LAH reacts, and then you can get the correct answer.